# Rails many-to-many unknown column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have two models, a User and a Message.

> A message ***has many*** recipients.
>
> A user ***has many*** received messages.
>
> Therefore, a message ***has and belongs to many*** recipients.

and

> A message ***has one*** creator.
>
> A user ***has many*** created messages.

I thought I had the correct structure, but I'm facing some issues, so I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

The migrations:

```
def self.up
    create_table :users_messages, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :message_id
        t.integer :user_id
    end

    add_index :users_messages, [:user_id, :message_id]
end
```

and

```
  def change
    add_column :messages, :creator_id, :integer
  end
```

**User.rb:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
belongs_to :message, foreign_key: "creator_id"
```

**Message.rb:**

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

But when I run this query:

```
Message.where("users.id = 1")
```

I get:

```
Unknown column 'users.id'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not trying to be anoying here, but you should choose one answer or at least up vote any, beacuse that's how this community works. If none of the answers satisfy you, you may update your question untill one does.

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin I know how the community works. None of the answers helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you've got several issues:

1. If you want to get all the messages for a given user, you would do something like, `user.messages`, not `Message.where("users.id = 1")`. Rails will take care of the SQL for you.
2. Your join table should be named `messages_users`, not `users_messages`. The table name should be the names of the joined tables **in alphabetical order**.
3. In `User.rb`, `belongs_to :message, foreign_key: "creator_id"` should be `has_many :created_messages, foreign_key: "creator_id"`, since a user can (I'm assuming) create many messages. `belongs_to` is always used on the model that has the foreign key. The other side of the relationship will be either `has_one` or `has_many`.

Comment: Regarding number 1, the reason I'm doing is because I have a complex query where I chain queries, and that part is just one part. How would I do that in an SQL query? Regarding number 2, is that a breaking issue? Meaning if I keep it as is, will things not work as expected? Or is that just a standard?

Comment: @moby The join table name really must be in alphabetical order, unles you explicitly declare it's name by adding `join_table: :users_messages` as an option in the has_and_belong_to_many association.

Comment: Ok, and what about the raw SQL query for number 1?

Comment: That's `user_one = User.find(1)` and then `user_one.messages` which will return all `messages` for `user` whose `id` is 1.

Comment: @moby Can you use named scopes to make that query? I've updated my answer, tell me if that went well

Comment: Generally speaking, unless you have a really hairy query (say that 10 times fast), you can chain ActiveRecord queries to your heart's content. So, you could do something like: `user.messages.where('attribute = ?', something).order('created_at DESC').includes(:third_attribute)`, etc. See the (ActiveRecord Query Interface Guide)[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html] and the (ActiveRecord::Base api documentation)[http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html] for more information. Or tell me what your query is and I'll try and help you achieve it the Rails way.

Comment: If you really want the raw SQL to get all the messages for a given user, see my comment regarding the named scope on @RafaelRamosBravin 's answer. If you're going to go this way, I agree with Rafael that a named scope is the cleanest way to do this, though I would name the scope `created_by_user`, but that's a minor detail.

Answer (score 1):

You have added the `creator_id` column in the messages table, so the `belongs_to` declaration should be in the Message model.

In the User model you should have `has_one :message`

The one who belongs is the one that has the ID

More details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)

---

Regarding to the messages query, if you create a scope in your Message class like:

```
    named_scope: :with_user, lambda{ |user|
      joins(:users).
      where("messages_users.user_id =  ?", user.id)
    }


   # EDIT: You could even use the association name as joins parameter and Rails will take care of the rest.
```

All you would have to do is call `Message.with_user(some_user)` and then keep chaining your other scopes.

Comment: I think the join should be more like this: `joins('INNER JOIN messages_users ON messages_users.message_id = messages.id')`. Then the where part should be: `where('messages_users.user_id = ?', user.id)`

Comment: I've updated my answer to a simplier form, thank you.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. This is slightly less efficient, since there are two joins, instead of one, but it's a hell of a lot easier to understand. I like it. As a side note for any weary wanderers of cyberspace, you can always chain `.explain` to the end of an ActiveRecord query to see what SQL it generates.

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me edit less than 6 characters, but your where call is missing a comma...

Answer (score 0):

This [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) helped me with this concept

There are two different ways to set up a many-to-many association in Rails. In this episode you will see how to implement both ways along with some tips on choosing the right one for your project.